# Create full SQL Server database script from within SQL Server & save for inclusion in Source Control

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016

I have 2 development machines. A laptop and desktop.

I synchronise code via Git between the two machines.

I need to synchronise database schema changes too. I had the idea of creating the full database (with or without data) in a .SQL file and including that in the source control folder.

You can manually do this by generating scripts from SSMS.

However, doing this manually any time I want to use the laptop is impractical. Can the generation of this script & placement in the source control folder be automated from within Visual Studio?

Or - is there a better way to synchronise database schemas between development machines?

I searched Google though wasn't even really sure what to look for. Is this possible?

Comment: You could try database project in SSDT

Comment: [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx)

Comment: In a nutshell what did you have in mind for SSDT exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding a [Database project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh864423(v=vs.103).aspx) to the solution, you'll be able to import an existing database schema, generating scripts for every object (table, view, stored proc, etc.) in it. These can then be added to source control.

SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) will also allow you to push back modifications made to the generated scripts back to the database.

Comment: sounds awesome - so the database becomes just like any other source controlled piece of code in essence?

Comment: Exactly! Making changes from Visual Studio and then publishing to one or more databases has never been easier.